# Problems with reading some avi videos (OpenCV with Python)

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have installed OpenCV 3.1.0 from the `sourfage` site. It is pre-built. I've followed this [site](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html#gsc.tab=0)'s tutorial. Tried to read a `mp4` video at first, but got negative result. After did some searching, I've included a path to the `opencv_ffmpeg310.dll` (at the same time, also to the `opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll`) which is in the directory of `C:\opencv\build\bin\`. But I can't play some `avi` videos (not all). I have installed `Xvid` but still got no any positive results. Whenever I've tried to play this `avi` video, I will get message that said `python.exe has stopped working`.

Any ideas how to solve this?